# How do i fill the previous day's not null value in my pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to fill the value of previous days and hour's value in my current day value which is having null value.

Consider my dataframe as below:-

|  | creTimestamp | CPULoad | instnceId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-01-22 18:48:00 | 22.0 | instanceA |
| 1 | 2021-01-23 20:25:00 | 23.0 | instanceA |
| 2 | 2021-01-22 18:42:00 | 22.0 | instanceA |
| 3 | 2021-01-22 15:24:00 | 23.0 | instanceB |
| 4 | 2021-01-24 20:25:00 | NaN | instanceA |
| 5 | 2021-01-22 08:53:00 | 22.0 | instanceA |
| 6 | 2021-01-23 19:43:00 | 23.0 | instanceB |
| 7 | 2021-01-23 15:24:00 | NaN | instanceA |
| 8 | 2021-01-24 18:48:00 | NaN | instanceA |
| 9 | 2021-01-24 01:51:00 | NaN | instanceB |
| 10 | 2021-01-24 15:24:00 | NaN | instanceA |

As, 2021-01-24 15:24:00 is NaN, then it looks for 2021-01-23 15:24:00 but that is null too, so it goes next for 2021-01-22 15:24:00 and fill the value for both 23 and 24 dates.

Result data frame should be as below :-

|  | creTimestamp | CPULoad | instnceId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-01-22 18:48:00 | 22.0 | instanceA |
| 1 | 2021-01-23 20:25:00 | 23.0 | instanceA |
| 2 | 2021-01-22 18:42:00 | 22.0 | instanceA |
| 3 | 2021-01-22 15:24:00 | 23.0 | instanceB |
| 4 | 2021-01-24 20:25:00 | 23.0 | instanceA |
| 5 | 2021-01-22 08:53:00 | 22.0 | instanceA |
| 6 | 2021-01-23 19:43:00 | 23.0 | instanceB |
| 7 | 2021-01-23 15:24:00 | 23.0 | instanceA |
| 8 | 2021-01-24 18:48:00 | 22.0 | instanceA |
| 9 | 2021-01-24 01:51:00 | NaN | instanceB |
| 10 | 2021-01-24 15:24:00 | 23.0 | instanceA |

For the non-matching, leave the null as it is.

**Please Note:-** I cant use ffill() or linear interpolation as it is disrupting my plots and taking the values randomly. I need to consider the same hour and minute for the previous days.
Also, i need to traverse max 7 days back to consider the values.

Please help me as i am struck here for long.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach here is join DF back to itself for previous values.  Have provided two example of this

1. previous day
2. timestamp where it's not `NaN`

Have left working columns in place for purpose of transparency.

```
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""    creTimestamp    CPULoad instnceId
0   2021-01-22 18:48:00 22.0    instanceA
1   2021-01-23 20:25:00 23.0    instanceA
2   2021-01-22 18:42:00 22.0    instanceA
3   2021-01-22 15:24:00 23.0    instanceB
4   2021-01-24 20:25:00 NaN instanceA
5   2021-01-22 08:53:00 22.0    instanceA
6   2021-01-23 19:43:00 23.0    instanceB
7   2021-01-23 15:24:00 NaN instanceA
8   2021-01-24 18:48:00 NaN instanceA
9   2021-01-24 01:51:00 NaN instanceB
10  2021-01-24 15:24:00 NaN instanceA
"""), sep="\t", index_col=0)

df.creTimestamp = df.creTimestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.creTimestamp)
# literally take previous day value
df2 = (df
 .assign(yesterday=lambda dfa: dfa.creTimestamp-pd.Timedelta(days=1))
 .merge(df.rename(columns={"creTimestamp":"yesterday"}).loc[:,["yesterday","CPULoad"]]
        , on="yesterday", suffixes=("", "_pre"), how="left")
 .assign(CPULoad=lambda dfa: dfa.CPULoad.fillna(dfa.CPULoad_pre))
)

# take timestamp forward,  beware if DF has multiple values for same timestamp
df2 = (df
 .assign(timestamp=lambda dfa: dfa.creTimestamp.dt.time)
 .merge(df.assign(timestamp=lambda dfa: dfa.creTimestamp.dt.time)
        .loc[:,["timestamp","CPULoad"]]
        .dropna()
        , on="timestamp", suffixes=("", "_pre"), how="left")
 .assign(CPULoad=lambda dfa: dfa.CPULoad.fillna(dfa.CPULoad_pre))
)
```

### output

```
       creTimestamp  CPULoad instnceId timestamp  CPULoad_pre
2021-01-22 18:48:00     22.0 instanceA  18:48:00         22.0
2021-01-23 20:25:00     23.0 instanceA  20:25:00         23.0
2021-01-22 18:42:00     22.0 instanceA  18:42:00         22.0
2021-01-22 15:24:00     23.0 instanceB  15:24:00         23.0
2021-01-24 20:25:00     23.0 instanceA  20:25:00         23.0
2021-01-22 08:53:00     22.0 instanceA  08:53:00         22.0
2021-01-23 19:43:00     23.0 instanceB  19:43:00         23.0
2021-01-23 15:24:00     23.0 instanceA  15:24:00         23.0
2021-01-24 18:48:00     22.0 instanceA  18:48:00         22.0
2021-01-24 01:51:00      NaN instanceB  01:51:00          NaN
2021-01-24 15:24:00     23.0 instanceA  15:24:00         23.0
```

### updated

- in large dataframe (not sample),  there can be multiple timestamps with different values
- make *timestamp* unique using `drop_duplicates()` so `merge()` will return number of rows in original DF
- will mean that *NaN* is filled with last observed value for a timestamp
- added additional key to join

```
# take timestamp forward,  beware if DF has multiple values for same timestamp
# taking last observed value to prevent merge generating duplicates
# also include instnceId in join key...
df2 = (df
 .assign(timestamp=lambda dfa: dfa.creTimestamp.dt.time)
 .merge(df.assign(timestamp=lambda dfa: dfa.creTimestamp.dt.time)
        .loc[:,["instnceId", "timestamp","CPULoad"]]
        .dropna()
        .drop_duplicates(subset=["instnceId","timestamp"], keep="last")
        , on=["instnceId","timestamp"], suffixes=("", "_pre"), how="left")
 .assign(CPULoad=lambda dfa: dfa.CPULoad.fillna(dfa.CPULoad_pre))
 .drop(columns=["timestamp","CPULoad_pre"])
)
```

Comment: Hi Rob, Thanks for the response.
What does this line signify.? 
df.creTimestamp = df.creTimestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.creTimestamp)

Comment: guarantees that the column is `datetime64` rather than `string` which then allows date functions to be used on the column

Comment: Hi Rob, This is increasing the size of the dataframe. So looks like after the merge to original dataframe , data is getting duplicated for the creTimestamp

Comment: really goes with the comment I left in the code...  increasing size,  there are two dimensions,  rows and columns.  If you mean rows (columns can be dropped) it means you have multiple rows with same timestamp and different values that are not NaN.  Can you provide a sample dataset where this is happening?  I'll take a look at it

Comment: have updated to show what I mean in comment of beware ...

Comment: Columns is not an issue.I can drop the columns. but it is happening with the rows. 
When i am plotting the graph, it is becoming with a flat line instead of sin-wave. I am wondering why is that happening, but for few rows it is updating correctly. Can i attach the dataset here, or how can i share it to you.?

Comment: Rob,i figured it out. duplicates due to instanceId . Can we add an extra condition of instnceId ? Each instance will have the duplicated timestamp. so may be group by or something.?

Comment: Its fine now!  Thanks Rob for your help. Really appreciate it. !

Comment: Rob, Can you help me with this too, please.?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66004487/add-data-for-the-missing-dates-based-on-previous-hour-data-in-pandas