# Add data for the missing dates based on previous hour data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time

I have a dataframe like below :-

| id | creTimestamp | CPULoad | instnceId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-01-22 18:00:00 | 22.0 | instanceA |
| 1 | 2021-01-22 19:00:00 | 22.5 | instanceA |
| 2 | 2021-01-22 20:00:00 | 23.5 | instanceA |
| 3 | 2021-01-22 18:00:00 | 24.0 | instanceB |
| 4 | 2021-01-22 19:00:00 | 24.5 | instanceB |
| 5 | 2021-01-22 20:00:00 | 22.5 | instanceB |
| 6 | 2021-01-24 18:00:00 | 23.0 | instanceA |
| 7 | 2021-01-24 19:00:00 | 23.5 | instanceA |
| 8 | 2021-01-24 20:00:00 | 24.0 | instanceA |
| 9 | 2021-01-24 18:00:00 | 25.5 | instanceB |
| 10 | 2021-01-24 19:00:00 | 28.5 | instanceB |
| 11 | 2021-01-24 20:00:00 | 23.5 | instanceB |

Missing dates date is for below:

2021-01-23
2021-01-25

I want to fill the rows for 2021-01-23 and 2021-01-25 also with the previous dates. Example, 22date  HR data should be considered.
I have a huge dataset where the entire data of the date can be missing for 2 hours .
The dates can be generated from the future date range too. Example for 2021-02-01 18:00:00 to 2021-02-02 18:00:00

updated dataframe should be as below:-

| id | creTimestamp | CPULoad | instnceId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-01-22 18:00:00 | 22.0 | instanceA |
| 1 | 2021-01-22 19:00:00 | 22.5 | instanceA |
| 2 | 2021-01-22 20:00:00 | 23.5 | instanceA |
| 3 | 2021-01-22 18:00:00 | 24.0 | instanceB |
| 4 | 2021-01-22 19:00:00 | 24.5 | instanceB |
| 5 | 2021-01-22 20:00:00 | 22.5 | instanceB |
| 6 | 2021-01-23 18:00:00 | 22.0 | instanceA |
| 7 | 2021-01-23 19:00:00 | 22.5 | instanceA |
| 8 | 2021-01-23 20:00:00 | 23.5 | instanceA |
| 9 | 2021-01-23 18:00:00 | 24.0 | instanceB |
| 10 | 2021-01-23 19:00:00 | 24.5 | instanceB |
| 11 | 2021-01-23 20:00:00 | 22.5 | instanceB |
| 12 | 2021-01-24 18:00:00 | 23.0 | instanceA |
| 13 | 2021-01-24 19:00:00 | 23.5 | instanceA |
| 14 | 2021-01-24 20:00:00 | 24.0 | instanceA |
| 15 | 2021-01-24 18:00:00 | 25.5 | instanceB |
| 16 | 2021-01-24 19:00:00 | 28.5 | instanceB |
| 17 | 2021-01-24 20:00:00 | 23.5 | instanceB |
| 18 | 2021-01-25 18:00:00 | 23.0 | instanceA |
| 19 | 2021-01-25 19:00:00 | 23.5 | instanceA |
| 20 | 2021-01-25 20:00:00 | 24.0 | instanceA |
| 21 | 2021-01-25 18:00:00 | 25.5 | instanceB |
| 22 | 2021-01-25 19:00:00 | 28.5 | instanceB |
| 23 | 2021-01-25 20:00:00 | 23.5 | instanceB |

The date range can be for last 7 days.

Please help me with this requirement.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to fill in columns CPULoad and InstanceID for the missing rows?

Comment: Previous date and the same hour data.if you see the updated datframe, CPUload has the data of 2021-01-22 19:00:00 , which is 22. Instance also should be same. like instance A in my example

Answer (score 2):

This is a continuation of [fill values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65991000/how-do-i-fill-the-previous-days-not-null-value-in-my-pandas-dataframe/65991916?noredirect=1#comment116699506_65991916)

- generate a DF that is combination of sampled hours and instances (`df2`)
- this generates 15 rows as there are 3 times for instanceA and 2 times for instanceB across 3 dates (2+3)*3
- then use same technique to fill both *CPULoad* and synthesized *memload*
- tested against pandas 1.0.1 as well as 1.2.0

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""id  creTimestamp    CPULoad instnceId
0   2021-01-22 18:00:00 22.0    instanceA
1   2021-01-22 19:00:00 22.0    instanceA
2   2021-01-22 20:00:00 23.0    instanceB
3   2021-01-23 18:00:00 24.0    instanceA
4   2021-01-23 20:00:00 22.0    instanceA
5   2021-01-24 18:00:00 23.0    instanceB
6   2021-01-24 20:00:00 23.5    instanceA
"""), sep="\t", index_col=0)

df.creTimestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.creTimestamp)
df["memload"] = np.random.random(len(df))

# generate a DF for each time in instance in each date
df2 = (pd.merge(
    # for each time in instance
    df.assign(timestamp=df.creTimestamp.dt.time)
        .loc[:,["instnceId","timestamp"]]
        .drop_duplicates()
        .assign(foo=1),
    # for each date
    df.creTimestamp.dt.date.drop_duplicates().to_frame().assign(foo=1),
    on="foo"
).assign(creTimestamp=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: dt.datetime.combine(r["creTimestamp"], r["timestamp"]), axis=1))
 .drop(columns="foo")
       # merge values back..
 .merge(df, on=["creTimestamp", "instnceId"], how="left")
)

# now get values to fill NaN
df2 = (df2.merge(df2.dropna().drop_duplicates(subset=["instnceId","timestamp"], keep="last"),
         on=["timestamp","instnceId"], suffixes=("","_pre"))
 .assign(CPULoad=lambda dfa: dfa.CPULoad.fillna(dfa.CPULoad_pre))
 .assign(memload=lambda dfa: dfa.memload.fillna(dfa.memload_pre))

)
```

### output

```
    instnceId timestamp        creTimestamp  CPULoad    creTimestamp_pre  CPULoad_pre
0   instanceA  18:00:00 2021-01-22 18:00:00     22.0 2021-01-23 18:00:00         24.0
1   instanceA  18:00:00 2021-01-23 18:00:00     24.0 2021-01-23 18:00:00         24.0
2   instanceA  18:00:00 2021-01-24 18:00:00     24.0 2021-01-23 18:00:00         24.0
3   instanceA  19:00:00 2021-01-22 19:00:00     22.0 2021-01-22 19:00:00         22.0
4   instanceA  19:00:00 2021-01-23 19:00:00     22.0 2021-01-22 19:00:00         22.0
5   instanceA  19:00:00 2021-01-24 19:00:00     22.0 2021-01-22 19:00:00         22.0
6   instanceB  20:00:00 2021-01-22 20:00:00     23.0 2021-01-22 20:00:00         23.0
7   instanceB  20:00:00 2021-01-23 20:00:00     23.0 2021-01-22 20:00:00         23.0
8   instanceB  20:00:00 2021-01-24 20:00:00     23.0 2021-01-22 20:00:00         23.0
9   instanceA  20:00:00 2021-01-22 20:00:00     23.5 2021-01-24 20:00:00         23.5
10  instanceA  20:00:00 2021-01-23 20:00:00     22.0 2021-01-24 20:00:00         23.5
11  instanceA  20:00:00 2021-01-24 20:00:00     23.5 2021-01-24 20:00:00         23.5
12  instanceB  18:00:00 2021-01-22 18:00:00     23.0 2021-01-24 18:00:00         23.0
13  instanceB  18:00:00 2021-01-23 18:00:00     23.0 2021-01-24 18:00:00         23.0
14  instanceB  18:00:00 2021-01-24 18:00:00     23.0 2021-01-24 18:00:00         23.0
```

Comment: I am getting error, Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike'. 
pandas version is 1.0.5.  
Secondly, i want for the dates which are not in this range. example 2021-02-01 18:00:00 to 2021-02-02 18:00:00. So merging with the orginal DF is giving NaN. Any idea how can we forward fill values for the time not in the dataset time range.

Comment: pandas version ? `pd.__version__` I'm using 1.2.0

Comment: pandas version is 1.0.5. 
Any clue on merging for the date ranges outside the min() and max() of the dataset?

Comment: your logic on required rows is odd.... instanceA has 3 times (18:00, 19:00, 20:00), instanceB 2 times (18:00, 20:00) and 3 dates,  so expected rows should be (3+2)*5 = 15

Comment: The base logic is for each timestamp, there should be 2 entries for each instance. one for instanceA    , instance B. But that is not my worry. I can create 2 diff DF based on each instance and merge them, but challenge is to fill the values for future dates.

Comment: I've updated - concept is same.  generate a DF which is the combinations you want then merge on time and instance to fill missing values

Comment: Failing for me due to pandas version.
Can i do this for multiple columns like for CPUload, there is memoryload column.. Can i apply lambda over the other set of columns too.?

Comment: I've downgraded to pandas 1.0.1 and the sample code works.  plus synthesized *memload*

Comment: Rob, I have updated the data requirement now. I mistyped it. Basically i want the data of 23 [past] and 25th/26/27[future]. for each instance A and B. Current code is working only for the data which is in the range . for future date , the data is coming as NaN. it is not referecing the date . Hope it is clear now. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I really don't comprehend any more,  you have a pivotal date - 24th,  everything before is past so untouchable and future (25th/26th/27th) where you want to generate from the past.  What's the definition of the requirements for the pivotal date?

Comment: Consider the case where the system was done for 23rd day.. where we cant capture the CPULoad stats. but we have data for 22nd. so we are building prediction pipline, instead of imputing the data with mean/median we are filling the values with previous day. That is why we are not using bfill or ffill or linear interpolate. 
Similarly , there was an outage on servers for 3 days[25,26,27].. on 28th i want to run this job so it fills up the data for these 3days based on 24th date as that is the last available data with me.The current existing data [23rd,24th] remains untouchable, as you said.

Comment: got it - techniques I have provided can fulfil your requirement.  it's no longer how,  but just coding time

Comment: yes, but its not generating the data correctly . and mind creTimestamp  is a datetime64[ns] field. that is why need help.